# Logs concerning failed IAX2 registration attempt missing on Asterisk server

Tags: logging, asterisk, voip

I am trying to register a VoIP softphone (Zoiper app for iOS) with an Asterisk installation via IAX2.

At present, this results in an error message "Registration Refused (29)" on the side of the softphone.

Can I obtain more information about this error from the side of Asterisk? At present I don't see anything related in `/var/log/asterisk/messages`.

Comment: For people finding their way here, I'll note the `requirecalltoken=no` setting, the lack of which was the reason I was running into this trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There are multiple logs in `/var/log/asterisk`, check them all**

**Debugging from the console**

You can also start asterisk from the console and enable debugging for `iax2`

```
# asterisk -r
asterisk*CLI> iax2 set debug on
asterisk*CLI>
```

Then try connecting again from your client. You should see more info on the console.

**For more info in `iax2` debugging**

```
asterisk*CLI> core show help iax2 set debug
iax2 set debug {on|off|peer}   -- Enable/Disable IAX debugging
iax2 set debug jb {on|off}     -- Enable/Disable IAX jitterbuffer debugging
iax2 set debug trunk {on|off}  -- Enable/Disable IAX trunk debugging
```

**And this**

```
asterisk*CLI> core show help logger
logger add channel             -- Adds a new logging channel
logger mute                    -- Toggle logging output to a console
logger reload                  -- Reopens the log files
logger remove channel          -- Removes a logging channel
logger rotate                  -- Rotates and reopens the log files
logger set level {DEBUG|NOTICE|WARNING|ERROR|VERBOSE|DTMF} {on|off} -- Enables/Disables a specific logging level for this console
logger show channels           -- List configured log channels
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same question today but got it to work after setting

> authdebug = yes

in **iax.conf**

Then the result in **/var/log/asterisk/messages** is

> [2017-01-17 09:37:09] NOTICE[1204] chan_iax2.c: No registration for peer '123' (from 123.45.67.89)

when trying to login with wrong credentials which can be filtered by fail2ban then, for example.